# Is there a future for a closed question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-overflow, closed-questions

I want to know , Is there a future for a closed question. Means what can be done after a question is closed? I know we can comment on closed question but what about other aspects about the question like "answering them", "up-voting or down-voting them" or "accepting answers for it" ?

Comment: Whatever you do: please DO NOT remove the auto-inserted duplicate links, which you did twice at another question.

Comment: what auto inserted duplicate links?

Comment: [These](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/77880/revisions) and [these](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/77690/revisions). Anything that is above the `<!-- End of automatically inserted text -->`.

Comment: is there a way to officially VETO a close vote on your question???

Answer (score 6):

Closed questions follow three general paths:

1. They are reopened by other community members,
2. They are closed but not deleted,
3. They are deleted.

When a question is deleted, all of the rep earned becomes null and void.  So if you recalc your reputation, all those votes are removed from your rep calculation.

You can still accept an answer on a closed question, but no further answers can be posted on it.  Obviously, you can't do anything else with a deleted question except, under certain circumstances, you can undelete it if you are the owner and have more than 10K of rep.  Community members with over 10K rep can also vote to undelete a question.

And so on.

Users with 10K rep can see deleted posts.  Most deletions are really "soft" deletions; the post remains in the database, but is not viewable by the majority of community members.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone with sufficient reputation can vote to [reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions) questions.

Also, if you've edited/improved your question and want to reopen it, you can probably ask moderators. That shouldn't be a lot of trouble for them.

Comment: I tried once to remove my errors from my question and asked the moderators to reopen it but they just roll-backed it to previous state

Comment: @Pankaj If some moderator's actions confused you, feel free to ask here. They have a lot of power, but they still answer to the community. Naturally, I can't say more about your problem without knowing details.

Comment: Or if you edited it you could visit the chat and ask for members of sufficient standing where present to reopen it. You'll probably be asked to demonstrate that you've made an effort to improve it (but a sufficient edit will usually demonstrate that)

Answer (score 2):

Even if a question stays closed, it can be useful.

If it has been closed as a duplicate, or when it has been closed and moved to another site, then it can still serve as an entry point for people who happen to find it through Google or some other search. Those can then follow the "duplicate of" links to get to a similar question which is still open (and probably has answers), or are automatically taken to the other site when browsing to the the migrated question. Other closed questions tell people what questions are not welcome on the site.

In short: some closed questions stay closed, and have a future in helping people find their way.