# Why is my question closed? How do I re-open it?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Why is my question closed? How do I re-open it?

Comment: Gawd.  Read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  You're off to a roaring start; one deleted answer (not an answer, should have been a comment, forum behavior, etc) and two deleted questions (off topic, don't-ask-this-type-of-question question).

Comment: Gee - this is a perfectly valid question which has not been answered!  I just had a question closed - I edited it, but despite reading multiple FAQ cannot figure out how/who/if it can be re-opened!

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347054/seeking-reporting-tools)?  If so it was closed as being too broad or unanswerable for this community.

For further information on closed questions see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78473/is-there-a-future-for-a-closed-question), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78529/how-do-we-get-the-attention-of-question-closers-to-re-open-a-question), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question).

Answer (score 1):

From the [faq:](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> Avoid asking subjective questions
>   where every answer is equally valid:
>   “What’s your favorite ______?”

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is not a product recommendation engine.  In a year, or even months, the question and answers would be outdated.  This makes the question, technically, "Too localized":

> - **Too localized**: "This question would only be relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet."

<sub><sup>[(source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-question/10583#10583))</sup></sub>